# $X$ is a column vector and $A$ is a matrix, What is $AX$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $X$ be a $n\times1$ column vector, whose components are all $0$ except for the $i$th component, and $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix, what is $AX$ ?

$$X=\pmatrix{0 \\ \vdots\\ 1 \\ \vdots \\0} \text{ and } 
A=\pmatrix{a_{11} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\ 
           \vdots & & \vdots\\
           a_{m1} & \ldots & a_{mn}}$$

I've tried several examples for $X$ and $A$, and I've noticed that there is a relation between the position of the $i$th component of X (which is $1$), and $AX$, but I can't like really make the generalization.

Comment: $AX$ is the $i$-th column of $A$. Try writing out each element of the product as a sum, in terms of the entries of $A$ and $X$. You'll see that many terms get zeroed out, and there is a very particular pattern in the terms that remain.

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of matrix multiplication to get a formula, of which most terms will be zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this question first you should understand that when we post multiply any column $X$ of size $n \times 1 $ to matrix A of size $ m \times n $ then how $AX$ look like ? $ \ \ $If $$X=\pmatrix{x_1 \\ \vdots\\ x_i \\ \vdots \\x_n} \text{ and } 
A=\pmatrix{a_{11} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\ 
           \vdots & & \vdots\\
           a_{m1} & \ldots & a_{mn}}$$
Then $AX =x_1 \pmatrix{a_{11} \\ \vdots\\ a_{m1}} + x_2 \pmatrix{a_{12} \\ \vdots\\ a_{m2}} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + x_i \pmatrix{a_{1i} \\ \vdots\\ a_{mi}} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + x_n \pmatrix{a_{1i} \\ \vdots\\ a_{mi}} = \pmatrix{a_{1i} \\ \vdots\\ a_{mi}}  $

In our case ,
$$X=\pmatrix{0 \\ \vdots\\ 1 \\ \vdots \\0} \text{ and } 
A=\pmatrix{a_{11} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\ 
           \vdots & & \vdots\\
           a_{m1} & \ldots & a_{mn}}$$
Then $AX =0 \pmatrix{a_{11} \\ \vdots\\ a_{m1}} + 0 \pmatrix{a_{12} \\ \vdots\\ a_{m2}} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + 1 \pmatrix{a_{1i} \\ \vdots\\ a_{mi}} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + 0 \pmatrix{a_{1i} \\ \vdots\\ a_{mi}} = \pmatrix{a_{1i} \\ \vdots\\ a_{mi}}  $

Answer (score 0):

Only one nonzero term enters each inner product and you get

$$X=\pmatrix{a_{1i}\\ a_{2i}\\ \vdots \\a_{ni}}$$